# WebGraph storage in Relational Databases

Tags: mysql, sql, web-applications, graph-algorithm, pagerank

How one can efficiently store the WebGraph in Relational databases such MySQL for playing with algorithms like PageRank? I think of creating two tables: one for URLs where only distinct URLs will be stored and another outgoing links table, for each url store its outgoing URL. Any ideas or any suggestions for efficient storage?

Comment: for those who voted to close: where should I ask this question? What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are specific databases which where created for such a purpose. Take a look at

- http://neo4j.org/
- https://launchpad.net/giraffedb